# Specifying language for Umbraco members

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm creating an internal CMS blog site using Umbraco 7. We need to show the content based on member's language preferences. Every member has to login to the site to view the blog content. Therefore I'm using Umbraco member functionality to cater that scenario.

I noticed there is a language selection while creating users for the back-office. Also, I'm aware of creating multiple site contents to support each language.

I went though https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/tutorials/multilanguage-setup/ article. But this is not what I'm looking for.

Are there any other way to specify `Mermeber's language preference` and show the content based on that after login to the system?

Or any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a "Preferred Language" property to your Member type (just a Content Picker I guess). Then you would have to do something in the front-end as well, perhaps like this: https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2014/razor-language-switcher/ . You'd also have to add code that updates the member property to whichever start node whenever a new one is selected, as well as a redirect mechanism so whenever a member enters the site they'd end up on the correct site.

If you're asking if all this exists already - in a package or something - I don't think so :-/